# How to make a java program that will search for a file in a given folder

Tags: java

I want to make a program that searches for a file in the given folder using the ***first few letters*** of the file name entered by the user.

So the thing is that the program must work like this :

```
     *User types first letters of the file name.
     *Program displays some files with the letters in its file name.
     *User selects one of them (Not really needed).
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works. We don't post answers to homework questions and we're not a "gimme teh codez" site.  You have to write the code and then if you encounter difficulties you can ask here and show your work.

Comment: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Comment: Your logic's correct. Why not program it? Or use Magic wand?

Comment: I try ed but my program needed  full file name,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  try with the below code for your search.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SearchFiles searchFilesObj = new SearchFiles();
        searchFilesObj.searchFiles(new File("/YourFolder/"), "TempFileName");
    }
    private List<String> searchFiles(File file,String fileNameToSearch) { // Directory name should  be passed  here
        private List<String> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.canRead()) {
                for (File currentFile : file.listFiles()) {
                    if (!currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                        if (fileNameToSearch.contains(currentFile.getName().toLowerCase())) {  // Also can use startsWith for the starting name         
                            listOfFiles.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                        }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return listOfFiles;
  }

}
```

Comment: Also you can try with String  indexOf() to search with only starting letter of the file  name.